# Error calling function postgresql .NET

Tags: c#, postgresql

ERROR: 42883: function insertvideo(character varying, character varying, double precision, integer) does not exist

But that Stored Procedure exist!!! Why continue this error???

This is my connection string:

```
 <connectionStrings>
        <add name="myConnection" connectionString="Server=127.0.0.1; 
                   User Id=postgres; Password=myPass; Database=myDB; "/>
      </connectionStrings>
```

Stored Procedure is in `public` schema and work correctly.

```
    using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AxWaveConnection"].ToString()))
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("insertvideo", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;


        cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("out_scope_id", NpgsqlDbType.Bigint));
            cmd.Parameters["out_scope_id"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("in_youtubeidvideo", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar, 15));
        cmd.Parameters["in_youtubeidvideo"].Value = VideoId;

        cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("in_title", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar, 200));
        cmd.Parameters["in_title"].Value = Title;

        cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("in_rating", NpgsqlDbType.Double));
        cmd.Parameters["in_rating"].Value = Rating;

        cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("in_viewcount", NpgsqlDbType.Integer));
        cmd.Parameters["in_viewcount"].Value = ViewCount;


        try
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            scopeID = Convert.ToInt64(cmd.Parameters["out_scope_id"].Value);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            scopeID = -1;        //Duplicate Record
        }

        conn.Close();
```

Comment: do you mean `Stored Procedure`?

Comment: One thing to consider is that postgres includes the parameter types as part of the function name.  So if you're passing parameters of a different type than the function definition, it will report it as not found even if the names are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Server=127.0.0.1; 
 add name="ConnectionStringName" connectionString="server=ServerNameOrIP;database=DataBasename;uid=UserID;pwd=Password; 
Check this Correctly an try again. It will work. Database connection not established.

Comment: the connection is working, otherwise he would give exception when opening.. dont it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass `function` in `NpgsqlCommand` command object. The only allowed there is sql query or the name of the stored procedure.

The best way to do is to create a `STORED PROCEDURE` with the function inside it and call the procedure in ado.net.

Comment: sorry but i'm a beginner in postgresql... i can create tables, views, functions, queries, reports, but not stored procedures... in all tutorials i'd never see: CREATE PROCEDURE

Comment: You CAN call a PostGreSQL function from ADO.Net.  It is very similar to calling a stored procedure on SQL Server.  PostGreSQL does not have stored procedures, only functions, which do for PostGreSQL the same basic things you would use stored procedures for in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Please add below connection string

```
<connectionStrings>
            <add name="myConnection" connectionString="Server=127.0.0.1; 
                       User Id=postgres; Password=myPass; Database=myDB; " providerName="postgre"/>
          </connectionStrings>
```